# Property [login] not found on type [com.app.dev.controller.LoginController]

Tags: jsf, el, propertynotfoundexception

I'm new to JSF and was wondering if how I can access the properties from a model and reuse it in the Controller class without getting null error or unknown properties.

Here is my code.

Model
**Login.java**

```
public class Login {
    
    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    
    
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }


    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }


    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }


    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }


    public Login() {
        
    }


    public Login(int id, String username, String password) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

And this is my controller

**LoginController.java**

```
@ManagedBean(name="loginController")
@SessionScoped
public class LoginController {

Login login= new Login();

public String validateUsernamePassword() throws Exception {
        boolean valid = DbUtil.validate(login.getUsername(), login.getPassword());
        if (valid) {
            HttpSession session = SessionUtils.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("username", login.getUsername());
            return "welcome";
        } else {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
                    null,
                    new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN,
                            "Incorrect Username and Passowrd",
                            "Please enter correct username and Password"));
            return "login";
        }
    }

}
```

And when I tried to access the managed bean on my xhtml file it doesn't know the username

**login.xhtml**

```
<body>
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputText value="Username" />
                <h:inputText id="username" value="#{loginController.login.username}"></h:inputText>
                <h:message for="username"></h:message>
                <br></br>

                <h:outputText value="Password" />
                <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{loginController.login.password}"></h:inputSecret>
                <h:message for="password"></h:message>
                <br></br>
            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:commandButton action="#{loginController.validateUsernamePassword}"
                value="Login"></h:commandButton>
        </h:form>
</body>
```

Then it gives me an error of

`Message /index.xhtml @12,74 value="#{loginController.login.username}": Property [login] not found on type [com.app.dev.controller.LoginController]`

If I tried to create a properties of username and password in the Controller it works but I think my model is not useful anymore and I cant also access the Id from the Database if I do manually create the properties on the ManagedBean.

Here is the source I've follow and tried but I want to update the password and needed the Id.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/jsf-authentication-login-logout-database-example

Comment: You forgot the getter method. See abovelinked duplicate.